# How to know if the resizing of a window is done from the left or from the right?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, mouseevent

I am using JavaFX to build a GUI and I'm having problems on knowing the mouse location when resized. The idea is that if a mouse gets on the very edge of the GUI it changes to a double sided arrow indicating that you can now press the mouse and resize the window.

I need the location of the mouse pointer on this edge, but I don't know how to do that. I need to know in which direction the window is resized.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** Added new options and discussed pros and cons.

This is tricky. The issue is that the window keeps track of its top, left, width, and height. When it is resized from the right or bottom, things are easy enough: the width or height change. But when it is resized from the left, both x and width must change. These two changes do not happen atomically, as x and width are stored as two independent properties.

The first approach to this is to keep track of the mouse coordinates, and just see if it's in the left half or the right half. (Obviously you can do the same with the height.) This approach is independent of any implementation details, but the user can cause it to fail by being extremely careful with the mouse. If you move the mouse to the right edge of the window to the exact pixel of the window boundary, then resize, you can see incorrect output.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

        class MouseLocation {
            double x,y ;
        }

        MouseLocation mouseLocation = new MouseLocation();
        scene.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
            mouseLocation.x = event.getX();
            mouseLocation.y = event.getY();
        });

        primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldWidth, newWidth) -> {
            if (mouseLocation.x < primaryStage.getWidth() / 2) {
                System.out.println("Resized from left");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Resized from right");
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The second approach is to keep track of the last known horizontal range of the window (minX and maxX), and update that range when the width changes. Then you can check to see whether the minX or maxX has changed. The problem with this approach is that it's dependent on undocumented implementation details. It appears (on my system, using the current version, etc) that when the window is resized from the left, x is changed first, then the width is changed. If that were to change in a subsequent release, the following would break:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

        class MutableDouble {
            double value ;
        }

        MutableDouble windowLeftEdge = new MutableDouble();
        primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldWidth, newWidth) -> {
            if (primaryStage.getX() == windowLeftEdge.value) {
                System.out.println("Resized from right");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Resized from left");
            }
            windowLeftEdge.value = primaryStage.getX() ;
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The third approach (that I can think of) is to coalesce changes that happen quickly into a single change. This is a bit tricky to program correctly, so instead of doing it from scratch, I used the [third party ReactFX framework](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) which models "event streams" and has a built-in mechanism for combining events that happen in quick succession. This is probably the most robust of the three solutions presented here, but at the cost of either a degree of complexity, or the inclusion of an external framework.

```
import java.time.Duration;

import org.reactfx.Change;
import org.reactfx.EventStream;
import org.reactfx.EventStreams;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.BoundingBox;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ReactFXVersion extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

        ObservableValue<Bounds> windowBounds = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
            new BoundingBox(primaryStage.getX(), primaryStage.getY(), primaryStage.getWidth(), primaryStage.getHeight()), 
            primaryStage.xProperty(), primaryStage.yProperty(), primaryStage.widthProperty(), primaryStage.heightProperty());

        EventStream<Change<Bounds>> bounds = EventStreams.changesOf(windowBounds)
                .reduceSuccessions((previousChange,  nextChange) -> 
                    new Change<>(previousChange.getOldValue(), nextChange.getNewValue()),
                    Duration.ofMillis(10));

        bounds.subscribe(boundsChange -> {
            Bounds newBounds = boundsChange.getNewValue();
            Bounds oldBounds = boundsChange.getOldValue();
            if (newBounds.getWidth() != oldBounds.getWidth()) {
                if (newBounds.getMinX() != oldBounds.getMinX()) {
                    System.out.println("Resized from left");
                } else if (newBounds.getMaxX() != oldBounds.getMaxX()) {
                    System.out.println("Resized from right");
                }
            }
            if (newBounds.getHeight() != oldBounds.getHeight()) {
                if (newBounds.getMinY() != oldBounds.getMinY()) {
                    System.out.println("Resized from top");
                } else if (newBounds.getMaxY() != oldBounds.getMaxY()) {
                    System.out.println("Resized from bottom");
                }
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will your method work if the edge is entered from outside the GUI? Will it return the mouse coordinates on the edges as well? I thought that the edges were an operating system thing and therefore not possible.

Comment: Ah, no. If you are very careful with the mouse, you can break it. I updated the answer to include some additional options.